# Kendo Grid page change disabling other jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and anytime I go to the next page or use my filter it won't fire my click events anymore for my `instructionsButton` or my `tipsButton`.  The click event works fine until i interact with the grid.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#clientsDb").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    pageSize: 15
                },
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                filterable: true,
                groupable: true,
                scrollable: false,
                resizable: true
            }).data("kendoGrid");

            $("#FieldFilter").keyup(function () {

                var value = $("#FieldFilter").val();
                var grid = $("#clientsDb").data("kendoGrid");

                if (value) {
                    grid.dataSource.filter({
                        logic: "or",
                        filters: [
                            { field: "TaskName", operator: "contains", value: value }
                        ]
                    });
                } else {
                    grid.dataSource.filter({});
                }
            });

            kendo.ui.editor.ColorTool.prototype.options.palette = "basic";
            $('.instructionsButton').one("click", function () {
                var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
                $(target + " " + ".editor").kendoEditor({
                    resizable: {
                        content: true,
                        toolbar: true
                    },
                    tools: [
                        "formatting",
                        "bold",
                        "italic",
                        "underline",
                        "justifyLeft",
                        "justifyCenter",
                        "justifyRight",
                        "justifyFull",
                        "insertUnorderedList",
                        "insertOrderedList",
                        "indent",
                        "outdent",
                        "createLink",
                        "unlink",
                        "foreColor",
                        "backColor"
                    ],
                    paste: function (ev) {
                        ev.html = $(ev.html).text();
                    }
                });
            });
            $('.tipsButton').one("click", function () {
                var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
                $(target + " " + ".editor").kendoEditor({
                    resizable: {
                        content: true,
                        toolbar: true
                    },
                    tools: [
                        "formatting",
                        "bold",
                        "italic",
                        "underline",
                        "justifyLeft",
                        "justifyCenter",
                        "justifyRight",
                        "justifyFull",
                        "insertUnorderedList",
                        "insertOrderedList",
                        "indent",
                        "outdent",
                        "createLink",
                        "unlink",
                        "foreColor",
                        "backColor"
                    ],
                    paste: function (ev) {
                        ev.html = $(ev.html).text();
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

WHAT I HAVE

```
$(document).delegate('.tipsButton', "click", function () {
                var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
                $(target + " " + ".editor").kendoEditor({
                    resizable: {
                        content: true,
                        toolbar: true
                    },
                    tools: [
                        "formatting",
                        "bold",
                        "italic",
                        "underline",
                        "justifyLeft",
                        "justifyCenter",
                        "justifyRight",
                        "justifyFull",
                        "insertUnorderedList",
                        "insertOrderedList",
                        "indent",
                        "outdent",
                        "createLink",
                        "unlink",
                        "foreColor",
                        "backColor"
                    ],
                    paste: function (ev) {
                        ev.html = $(ev.html).text();
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a delegate, as the elements not on the page aren't being bound to the event.  If you do something similar to:

```
$(document).delegate("classOrId", "eventType", function () { 
    // Do function stuff here
});
```

Then the `eventType` should fire on the elements on all of the pages with the `classOrId` you put in.

Comment: The problem I'm running into is it just creates the editor over and over. i only need it to run once per click.

Comment: What do you mean by creates it over and over?  You want one editor for ALL elements?  If so, why not just build the one and hide/show it as needed (using the delegation code above)?

Comment: There are about 27 "tasks" on page, and each one gets its own editor..if it builds them all at once the page load is insane. so i was implementing on click with the code above.  What I mean is if i put delegation in instead of `.one` if i click my icon that brings up the editor, it keeps putting editors within editors.  I added the code i changed

Comment: Ok, so it is using the same editor, just creating a new one within that one without doing any housekeeping.  I agree trying to load up a ton of editors would cause a browser to have an aneurysm.  Unfortunately the cleanest way I can think of would be to destroy existing instances of the editor, then call a new editor on click.  I can't think of any way to bind to an element that isn't the DOM.  Could you do a fiddle?